# Configuring target platform for my Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, configuration

I have a visual studio solution with three projects.  I want to configure them all for x64 (as I have a X64 machine). I have created the x64 configuration as you can see in the following image.

[image: configuration page]

The x64 configuration can be applied to the first and the third project. It lists in the drop-down box like shown in the following image.

[image: drop-down has x64]

The project in the center is dependent on the project on top and below it, both. But, this project alone does not show x64 in the drop down. Here is the image:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my problem. I had created the configuration X64 from one of the projects. I had to delete the configuration from the other projects and create it again in the other project and only then, it allowed me to set the configuration for that project. When this deleting and re-creating the configuration was done for each project, it worked fine. If only the properties of one project did not show the configuration created in other projects, or if showing, it had allowed to set that configuration to other projects too, then the problem would not have come. I think this is a bug in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Click on `<new>` and add `X64` and choose to *copy its settings* from `Win32` then change the settings that you want by yourself.

Comment: I did that... Did you see the screenshots??? The setting for X64 already exists but doesn't show in the drop-down of only one project out of the three. That's my problem.

Comment: I mean you should do it for that project (each one sepeartly) did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I have done that for all the projects, but for that project, it shows a dialog box saying, `This platform could not be created because a solution platform of the same name already exists.` But, the drop-down menu does not contain the platform name.

Comment: mmmm.. what is importrigexport ? what language?

Comment: its in c++ and other two are also in c++

Comment: then I do not know :(  From the information you provided, it hard to know. You may find someone who faced this before so he can answer. Or ask a colleague to see it on your machine . good luck

Comment: Thanks. But I need the solution badly.